# How to correctly save dialog fragment's state containing parent fragment reference in callback?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Constructor (note ListPickerHandler)

```
public StarredListPickerDialogFragment(ListPickerHandler h) {
        handler = h;
        mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<StarredList>();
    }
```

this is how I call parent fragment methods (defined implementing ListPickerHandler interface)

```
 alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button negative = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                Button positive = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                positive.setEnabled(false);
                negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        handler.onNegativeButtonAction(mSelectedItems);
                    }
                });
                positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        handler.onPositiveButtonAction(mSelectedItems);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Now troubles come when android os calls onSaveInstanceState(). Handler is no more defined and I actually have no clues to handle this situation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by casting (when bundle is not null) the parent fragment to ListPickerHandler which is the interface implemented by the invoking fragment